# Extracting lines from zone file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, bind

I have a DNS zone file that looks like the following:

```
record A 1.1.1.1
       A 1.1.1.2
       A 1.1.1.3
other_record A 1.1.1.4
             A 1.1.1.5
another_rec  A 1.1.1.6
```

I need to extract all lines that belong to record (so the first one and the two below it) without any of the other lines (the actual file has many more records like this so greping the first line and the 2 other below is not a valid solution).

Expected result:

```
record A 1.1.1.1
       A 1.1.1.2
       A 1.1.1.3
```

Comment: at least, post the expected result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest done. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^[^[:space:]]/{f = ($1=="record" ? 1 : 0)} f' file
```

Comment: This one works. Can you explain the solution? Also how can i achieve the opposite and remove "record"? Thanks!

Comment: for every input line that doesn't start with a space set a "found" variable `f` to 1 if the line starts with "record" and 0 otherwise. For every line if `f` is non-zero then print that line. Swap 1 and 0 to get the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^record/{:a;n;/^\S/Q;ba};d' file
```

This terminates following the first occurrence of `record`,
or:

```
sed '/^\S/h;G;/^record/MP;d' file
```

This prints all occurrences of `record`.

Comment: It works, can you explain the solution? Also can you explain how to delete the "record"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could also think about using a dns zone file parsers available in various languages like python etc.

Once you have a handle on zone file content as an object then its pretty easy to manipulate it the way you want.

I got this one after doing quick web search - https://github.com/blockstack/zone-file-py . (there are bunch of others... you need to see which one works for you best)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps.

```
awk '/^[a-z]+/ && !/^record/{flag=""} /^record/{flag=1} flag'  Input_file
```

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '!/_/&&NR!=5' file

record A 1.1.1.1
       A 1.1.1.2
       A 1.1.1.3
```